# Redux Store: cannot read property and store is undefinied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I start working in a redux project with redux and it's an entirely chaos,
I set up an a Store as interface, like this:

```
interface Store {
  ads: {
    loading: boolean;
    data: Ad[];
    errors: Error;
    isPro: boolean; 
  };
}

interface Ad {
  id: any;
  title: any;
  body: any;
  price: any;
  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
}
```

I have this constant to refer as an action to dispatch after:

```
export const TYPE_ADD_JOB_ANNOUNCEMENT_REQUEST = "action/addJobAnnouncementRequest";
```

And then i have my reducer:

```
   import {
  TYPE_ADD_JOB_ANNOUNCEMENT_REQUEST, 
} from "../constants/actions";

export const reducer = (Store: Store, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case TYPE_ADD_JOB_ANNOUNCEMENT_REQUEST:
      console.log("Test");
      return {
        ...Store,
        annuncio: [...Store.ads.data, action.payload]
      };

    default:
      console.log("dont return nothing");
      break;
  }
  return Store;
};
```

I already the ReduxDevTools working, i test it with different console log and it work fine, now why when the reduxdevotools try to dispatch an action with the payload, (Example:

```js
{
  type: 'action/addJobAnnouncementRequest',
  payload: { title: "test" }
}
```

It give me different errors if i try different test but with the same mode, like

> store is undefinied,

or

> cannot read property "ads"

I think there is a problem with my javascript syntax or i dont know, can anyone help me?

Comment: We need to see more of your reducer. The interface says `ads` is there, but we cant see if thats true. It also looks like you might be trying to use the interface as the state object, but can't tell

Comment: Edited bro, can you give a look?

Answer (score 0):

You should also initialize your state object as it looks like that is where your error about `ads` is coming from. You can use `store` or `Store` instead of `state` if you choose.

```js
const initialState: Store = {
  ads: {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    errors: '',
    isPro: false, 
  };
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPE_ADD_JOB_ANNOUNCEMENT_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        ads: [...state.ads.data, action.payload] // I'm assuming you meant `ads` here?
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: i forget to say, its typescript, its the same?

Comment: Well since the typings get stripped out before it ever gets to the browser, it might not throw an error, but it could error in the compiler. Not 100% sure. I think the main issue is initializing the reducer.

Comment: Looking into if further, I don't think the same names are a problem [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798480/9381601). Personally I just find it confusing. But I'll remove that part from my answer