TSX : 'Routes' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Routes'?
Typescript code (.tsx)
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<span>Home Page</span>} />
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default AppRoutes;

Here's the code (https://i.sstatic.net/21ZT7tM6.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/7EYp6weK.png)
'Routes' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
Why this is not working ...

Is your linter configured for JSX? Please share any config options that you have set.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059408/reactjs-and-typescript-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-ts

I always have different unexplainable errors while using other version of react-router dom that is not version 6. I would suggest you use the compactible version of react-router dom or the latest version.
npm install react-router-dom@6

or
npm install react-router-dom@latest


I guess you are not using any wrapper BrowserRouter components.
Remove/uninstall your package and install react-router-dom@latest as GifftyCode says.
You that code in your file then I hope it will be work
// App.tsx
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<span>Home Page</span>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

Make sure that your App components are on your main.tsx files

replaced code in App.tsx like yours , it does not work , please see the images i have shared in que

Your main.tsx file should be looks like this <React.StrictMode><AppRoutes /></React.StrictMode> since you are using AppRoutes.tsx file.
once you have done that then just copy paste the code that I shared on your AppRoutes.tsx file.
