Get SVGImageElement for Canvas from embedded svg
How can I get an SVGImageElement from an SVG defined directly in the HTML that can be drawn on a Canvas?
HTML:
<div id="canvas-div">
   <canvas id="my-canvas">
   </canvas>
</div>

<div hidden>
   <svg width="100" height="100" id="svg-circle">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   </svg>
</div>

TS:
  let svgImagAny: any = document.getElementById("svg-circle");
  // let svgImg: SVGImageElement = svgImagAny as SVGImageElement; // Doesn't work
  this.context.drawImage(/* What goes here?*/ svgImg, 0, 0, 25, 25);

Edit: Thanks for the suggestion to look at How to access SVG elements with JavaScript? but this seems to rely on loading content. I specifically want to define the SVG entirely inline and then draw it on a Canvas. If I missed something there please point it out.

HTML:
<div id="canvas-div">
   <canvas id="my-canvas">
   </canvas>
</div>

<div hidden>
   <img src="/your/svg/path.svg" alt="Alternative text" id="svg-circle" />
</div>

TS:
 let svgImage = document.getElementById("svg-circle") as HTMLImageElement;
  this.context.drawImage(svgImage, 0, 0, 25, 25);


Thanks for the response but I need to be able to define the SVG inline, not load from content.

Found the answer eventually. Results left here in case it helps anyone else.
This gave me what I needed (with thanks to https://www.shecodes.io/athena/13871-how-to-inline-svg-directly-inside-of-html#:~:text=The%20svg%20element%20specifies%20the,html):
// Why InstanceType<typeof Image>?
// Using Image causes TS 2749: Image refers to a Value but it being used as a type
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059408/reactjs-and-typescript-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-ts

GetImageAsXMLFromInline(id: string): InstanceType<typeof Image> {

   let svgElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id);
   let xml: string = encodeURIComponent(svgElement.outerHTML);
   var image_data = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + xml;

   let svgImg = new Image();
   svgImg.src = image_data;

   return svgImg;
}


DrawImg() {
   if ((this.cursor_x == null) || (this.cursor_y == null))
      return;

   this.context.save();
   // this.context.fillStyle = "rgb(0 0 0 / 5 %)";
   this.context.fillStyle = "white";
   this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

   let img: InstanceType<typeof Image> = this.GetImageAsXMLFromInline("line-with-markers");
   this.context.drawImage(img, this.cursor_x, this.cursor_y, 250, 250);
}

This also works but seems a bit more costly at run-time (ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140386/5686593):
private xml_ser = new XMLSerializer();

GetImageAsB64FromInline(id: string): InstanceType<typeof Image> {

   let svgImgAny: any = document.getElementById(id);

   // get svg data
   var xml = this.xml_ser.serializeToString(svgImgAny);

   // make it base64
   var svg64 = btoa(xml);
   var b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
   var image64 = b64Start + svg64;

   // set it as the source of the img element
   let svgImg = new Image();
   svgImg.src = image64;

   return svgImg;
}

