# Typescript const name and interface - how to implements?

Tags: typescript, interface, symbols

```
export declare const TerminalWidgetOptions; unique synbol;
export interface TerminalWidgetOptions {
    endpoint: Endpoint.Options,
    id: string,
    caption: string,
    label: string
    destroyTermOnClose: boolean
}
```

With this code when I create a class implementing this interface, I get an error :
error TS2507: Type 'unique symbol' is not a constructor function type.

I don't understand why TypeScript doesn't see the interface.

Is someone could explain me ?

Comment: Is the first line supposed to be `export const TerminalWidgetOptions: unique symbol`? Because, if so, I'm not sure what this code is trying to do. You declare a constant which is a symbol and an interface which is completely different both having the same name? Also, there is a `const` but it's not assigned to anything.

Comment: I forgot there is a declare front of the const and I have to use this code but it's not mine. I try to implement the interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript variable name as interface type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798156/typescript-variable-name-as-interface-type)

Comment: Let me reiterate what @VLAZ said. `const TerminalWidgetOptions; unique synbol;` MAKES NO SENSE, with or without `declare`.  It's just a bunch of syntax errors.  I found [the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798156/typescript-variable-name-as-interface-type) and you are supposed be assigning a value to the `const` which is a `Symbol` that you create by calling `Symbol("TerminalWidgetOptions")`.  You are neither assigning a value nor creating a `Symbol`.  Is this a code file or a declaration file? @glavigno's answer declares the `const` but doesn't create it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to declare it before defining and exporting it ?

```
declare const TerminalWidgetOptions: unique symbol;

export interface TerminalWidgetOptions {
    endpoint: Endpoint.Options;
    id: string;
    caption: string;
    label: string;
    destroyTermOnClose: boolean;
}
```

I referred to the official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol).

Comment: Same problem with declare

Comment: Which version of Typescript are you using ?